# Error while creating sql engine using sqlalchemy - image not found

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm testing a small python code
When I try to create an engine that connects with MySQLDB I face the following error:

statement:

```
engine = create_engine(connection_url, echo=False,server_side_cursors=True,execution_options=dict(stream_results=True),encoding="utf-8")
```

and the error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-da54be46d1c6> in <module>
----> 1 engine = create_engine(connection_url, echo=False,server_side_cursors=True,execution_options=dict(stream_results=True),encoding="utf-8")

~/anaconda3/envs/venv_merge/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py in create_engine(*args, **kwargs)
    477     strategy = kwargs.pop("strategy", default_strategy)
    478     strategy = strategies.strategies[strategy]
--> 479     return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
    480 
    481 

~/anaconda3/envs/venv_merge/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py in create(self, name_or_url, **kwargs)
     85                 if k in kwargs:
     86                     dbapi_args[k] = pop_kwarg(k)
---> 87             dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
     88 
     89         dialect_args["dbapi"] = dbapi

~/anaconda3/envs/venv_merge/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py in dbapi(cls)
    116     @classmethod
    117     def dbapi(cls):
--> 118         return __import__("MySQLdb")
    119 
    120     def on_connect(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/venv_merge/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py in <module>
     16 from MySQLdb.release import __version__, version_info, __author__
     17 
---> 18 from . import _mysql
     19 
     20 if version_info != _mysql.version_info:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/my.user/anaconda3/envs/venv_merge/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/my.user/anaconda3/envs/venv_merge/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are working with MacOS, error you have posted is due to incorrect installation of MySQL and MySQLdb package. Try the following instruction to fix MySQLdb and then try again:

```
brew install mysql
brew unlink mysql
brew install mysql-connector-c
sed -i -e 's/libs="$libs -l "/libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"/g' /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
pip install MySQL-python
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
brew link --overwrite mysql
pip install MySQL-python
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Hussain, thanks for respondingwhen i tried to install mysql as per the first command I got this: Error: /usr/local/opt/mysql is not a valid keg

Comment: still getting the same error after updating , but I managed to solve the issue although still feeling this is not fixing but workaround an existing problem , I just copied the missing file into the path in which python is searching for the library in:  cp -R /usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/