# PyCharm: ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.20 only when I run django app from IDE

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am working on a simple Django app using PyCharm community edition, python 3.9 and ubuntu 20.04. The project's virtual environment is in folder `[project root]/venv/`

When I start the app from the pycharm terminal window I execute the following commands and everything works fine (no import errors):

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
python manage.py runserver
```

When I start the app from the IDE running configuration, I get an `ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Given that the project runs via the terminal, I believe that my python installation and my virtual environment are ok. I guess that this should not happen if the IDE run/debug configuration was using the same virtual environment hosted in `[project root]/venv/`. Therefore, I suppose the run/debug configuration is not correctly configured, or there is something missing in my paths. I have checked other posts but I could not find a solution.

The following screenshots depict my run/debug configuration and the setup of my virtual environment in the PyCharm IDE (also showing the respective packages).
[image]
[image]

Could somebody please guide me?

Is there a way to confirm that my run debug configuration uses the same virtual environment as the one used via the terminal? Is there a setting in PyCharm IDE that I should check for? Do I miss something fundamental about how do python virtual environments work?

Comment: I tried these steps in the past to get MySQL python working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211219/error-while-creating-sql-engine-using-sqlalchemy-image-not-found/59211539#59211539, but you are saying in your case you can launch app from terminal not from PyCharm, so not sure if this will help.

Comment: @HussainBohra: Indeed, since the app works when I call it from the terminal, I would expect that everything is fine with my packages setup and therefore, I would not reinstall packages. Is there a way to confirm that my run debug configuration uses the same virtual environment as the one used when I start the app using the terminal?

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas, have you managed to solve this? I'm facing the same problem (not Django, though).

Comment: @ademarizu No, I have not solved it. Actually I worked without using the PyCharm

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas, sad... at command line, just like for you, it works just fine, but it would be nice to have it working on PyCharm. Shame =(